# JavaScript framework to work with existing HTML

Tags: library, javascript, html, framework

Is there a JavaScript framework to work with existing HTML content?

Use case - The server transfers existing HTML content to the client (browser). The HTML is generated at the server using XSLT transformation on XML data.

I am looking for a Javascript framework to manage user interaction like showing/hiding certain parts of the page based on user input selections adding form validation and adding new components to the server-sent form based on user interaction.

What about existing frameworks?

- jQuery - too old
- React is too heavy and it is all virtual DOMs, I will need the actual DOM modified so that when the content is modified, the HTML element stays within the page during the form submission.
- I am currently using Alpine.js library, but it has its issues with sharing information across components/sections of the page.
- I am not familiar with the new frameworks like Solid.js, Svelte. Willing to learn if they work with existing HTML elements

Does anyone have any recommendations on my requirements?

Comment: What's wrong with jQuery being old?

Comment: I don't prefer jQuery

Comment: What specifically do you not like about it? We'd need to know your preferences.